# Backbone, getting parameters others than data in collection

Tags: backbone.js

Given the following json:

```
 { 
   "admin": false,
   "data": [
     {
      value: key, 
      value :key
     },
     {
      value: key, 
      value :key
     }
    ]
 }
```

I defined my collection like this:

```
 var myCollection = Backbone.Collections.extend({
     url: myurl.com,
     parse : function (response) {
        return response.data;
     }
 });
```

It works like charm, it fill my collection with the data array, however, into the tamplate, I need to render some content when admin is equal true. But I cannot find a way to pass that value to the template.

Any chance any of u kind guys can point it into the right direction to solve this?

Comment: when you need the information of admin let it be dont remove it in parse, paste your template also so that i can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could save the admin flag as a property of the collection in the parse method:

```
var myCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: myModel,
    isAdmin: false,
    ...
    parse : function (response) {
        this.isAdmin = response.admin; //save admin flag from response
        return response.data;
    }
});
```

Then you could retrieve it and pass it to your template or use it in any other way in the view render method:

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({    
    collection: new myCollection(),
    ...
    render: function(){
        //retrieve admin flag from collection:
        var isAdmin = this.collection.isAdmin;

        //you could add it into the json you pass to the template
        //or do anything else with the flag

    }                               
});
```

You can try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lx68fLvr/) with a very basic render function.

Comment: thank u a lot man! I wouldn't figure it out myself, it worked like charm!

Comment: This was also helpful because I'm using Python/Flask, and jsonify doesn't allow top level arrays, so I can extract the data this way.